# Creating custom VCF file

Tags: vcf, genomics, mutect2

I'm stuck on what seems to be a banal problem, but I can't work out where the issue is. I need to create some customised VCF files that specify particular variants of interest.

This is a custom VCF I created for this [variant](http://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Variation/Explore?r=20:4699252-4700252;v=rs74315403;vdb=variation;vf=1054935347):

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.3
##FILTER=<ID=PASS,Description="All filters passed">
##fileDate=20240308
##source=Ensembl
##reference=GRCh38
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL  FILTER    INFO
20  4699752 rs74315403  G   A   .   .  .
```

The formatting seems correct to me; the values are separated by tabs, all relevant column headers are present, there is a value for every header. I try to use it in the Mutect2 `--alleles` and `-L` options, as follows:

```
gatk Mutect2 \
  -R ref.fa \
  --alleles my.vcf.gz  \
  -L my.vcf.gz\
  -I input.bam \
  -O output.vcf
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: htsjdk.tribble.TribbleException$MalformedFeatureFile: Unable to parse header with error: Your input file has a malformed header: there are not enough columns present in the header line: #CHROM     POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL  FILTER    INFO, for input source: path/to/my.vcf
        at htsjdk.tribble.TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.readHeader(TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.java:265)
        at htsjdk.tribble.TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.<init>(TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.java:104)
        at htsjdk.tribble.TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.<init>(TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.java:129)
        at htsjdk.tribble.AbstractFeatureReader.getFeatureReader(AbstractFeatureReader.java:121)
        at org.broadinstitute.hellbender.engine.FeatureDataSource.getTribbleFeatureReader(FeatureDataSource.java:433)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: htsjdk.tribble.TribbleException$InvalidHeader: Your input file has a malformed header: there are not enough columns present in the header line: #CHROM       POS     ID      REF    ALT      QUAL  FILTER    INFO
        at htsjdk.variant.vcf.AbstractVCFCodec.parseHeaderFromLines(AbstractVCFCodec.java:149)
        at htsjdk.variant.vcf.VCFCodec.readActualHeader(VCFCodec.java:117)
        at htsjdk.tribble.AsciiFeatureCodec.readHeader(AsciiFeatureCodec.java:79)
        at htsjdk.tribble.AsciiFeatureCodec.readHeader(AsciiFeatureCodec.java:37)
        at htsjdk.tribble.TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.readHeader(TribbleIndexedFeatureReader.java:263)
```

Supposedly there's something wrong with the header. Can you spot the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like your header isn't tab separated. You can check for the presence of tabs with `od -c`. So, to check the header, do

```
zgrep '^#C' my.vcf.gz | od -c
```

Then check the output, it should show `\t` between each header field, like this:

```
$ zgrep '^#C'  variants.vcf.gz | od -c
0000000   #   C   H   R   O   M  \t   P   O   S  \t   I   D  \t   R   E
0000020   F  \t   A   L   T  \t   Q   U   A   L  \t   F   I   L   T   E
0000040   R  \t   I   N   F   O  \t   F   O   R   M   A   T  \t   E   D
0000060   2   0   0   1   3   9   6  \n
0000070
```

Comment: Nice on the `od -c`. I generally use `cat -te`, but this looks easier to eyeball